# Flatten 'trees' with relationships expressed in two columns with Pandas or Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have collection of family trees that have a format similar to the below follows:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \ / \
D  E F  G
  / \
 .. ..
```

Expressed in the following two columns (which contain multiple trees):

| child | parent |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| B | A |
| C | A |
| D | B |
| ... | ... |

What is the most efficient way to flatten this so that in a new column I get the upper most parent?

i.e. B = A, D = A...?

| child | parent | highest_parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | A |
| B | A | A |
| C | A | A |
| D | B | A |
| ... | ... | ... |

Ideally I would like to do this in Spark (given the size of the dataset) but could also try Pandas?

I currently cant wrap my head around doing this efficiently without some very intensive recursive function for each level (even if my trees are at most 3 levels deep).

Comment: in pyspark and knowing you only have 3 levels deep, I think using two `join` would be the most easy to implement and probably fast enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas you may check with `networkx`

```
df=df.dropna()
import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'parent', 'child',create_using=nx.DiGraph())
def find_root(G,node):
    if len(list(G.predecessors(node)))>0:
        root = find_root(G,list(G.predecessors(node))[0])
    else:
        root = node
    return root

df['child'].apply(lambda x : find_root(G,x))

Out[109]: 
1    A
2    A
3    A
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "child": ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','A1','B1','C1','D1','E1','F1','G1','H1','I1'],
    "parent": [np.NaN,'A','A','B','B','C','C','G','G',np.NaN,'A1','A1','B1','B1','C1','C1','G1','G1']
})
```

```
upper_parent_list = list(df[df['parent'].isna()]['child'])
['A', 'A1']
```

```
df['upper_parent'] = df['parent'].fillna(df['child'])

   child parent upper_parent
0      A    NaN            A
1      B      A            A
2      C      A            A
3      D      B            B
4      E      B            B
5      F      C            C
6      G      C            C
7      H      G            G
8      I      G            G
9     A1    NaN           A1
10    B1     A1           A1
11    C1     A1           A1
12    D1     B1           B1
13    E1     B1           B1
14    F1     C1           C1
15    G1     C1           C1
16    H1     G1           G1
17    I1     G1           G1
```

```
while df['upper_parent'].isin(upper_parent_list).sum()!=df.shape[0]:
    for up_par in upper_parent_list:
        child_list = list(df[df['upper_parent'].isin([up_par])]['child'])
        df['upper_parent'] = np.where(df['parent'].isin(child_list), up_par, df['upper_parent'])
print(df)

   child parent upper_parent
0      A    NaN            A
1      B      A            A
2      C      A            A
3      D      B            A
4      E      B            A
5      F      C            A
6      G      C            A
7      H      G            A
8      I      G            A
9     A1    NaN           A1
10    B1     A1           A1
11    C1     A1           A1
12    D1     B1           A1
13    E1     B1           A1
14    F1     C1           A1
15    G1     C1           A1
16    H1     G1           A1
17    I1     G1           A1
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way in pyspark, **with only 3 levels**. Note that the last row has 4 levels in the example and fails, not your case hopefully but to see it

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# create toy data
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'child':list('ABCDEFGHIJKLM'), 
                    'parent':['','A','A','B','B','C','C','E', '', 'I','J','K','L']})
# convert to spark dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

# coalesce the column parent
df = df.withColumn('parent', F.when(F.col('parent')!='', F.col('parent'))
                              .otherwise(F.col('child')))

# do self join using alias to direct to the right columns
res = (
    df.alias('df1')
      .join(df.alias('df2'), F.col('df1.parent') == F.col('df2.child'))
      .join(df.alias('df3'), F.col('df2.parent') == F.col('df3.child'))
      .select(['df1.child', 'df1.parent',F.col('df3.parent').alias('highest_parent')])
)
```

and you get

```
res.orderBy('child').show()
+-----+------+--------------+
|child|parent|highest_parent|
+-----+------+--------------+
|    A|     A|             A|
|    B|     A|             A|
|    C|     A|             A|
|    D|     B|             A|
|    E|     B|             A|
|    F|     C|             A|
|    G|     C|             A|
|    H|     E|             A|
|    I|     I|             I|
|    J|     I|             I|
|    K|     J|             I|
|    L|     K|             I|
|    M|     L|             J| <--this one 4 levels so fail, could add a join if needed
+-----+------+--------------+
```